# sequence of select query not right

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I tried to query my database for data. However, when I query for my data, I only managed to get the data after my last alert, which is the `alert("Total...")` For instance, I run the code below, the alert for "result row:" only appear after the last alert appear. May I know why?

```
function (result) {

           window.location.href = "#/app/CustHomePage";

           var totalBalance = 0;
           var tableRef = document.getElementById("myList").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];



           for (var i = 0; i < tableRef.rows.length; i++) {

               alert(tableRef.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML.substr(1));

               var addBalance = parseInt(tableRef.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML.substr(1));
               totalBalance = totalBalance + addBalance;
           }

           alert(totalBalance);
           var myText = result.text;
           var myTextTwo = myText.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
           alert(myTextTwo);
           var custBal;



           var myDB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "mySQLite.db", location: 'default' });

           alert("Hello");

           myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
               alert("Hello");
               transaction.executeSql("SELECT customerBalance FROM customer where nric = '" + myTextTwo + "'", [], function (tx, results) {
                   var len = results.rows.length;
                   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                       custBal = results.rows.item(i).customerBalance;
                       alert("result row" + results.rows.item(i).customerBalance);
                       alert("CustomerBal" + custBal);
                   }
               },
                 function(tx, error)
                 {

                 }
                   );
           });



           alert("Total after entitled discount: ");
           alert("Transaction successful, Next Customer Please");

       }
```

Comment: You need a callback, your code is continuing to execute even though the database pull hasn't finished yet. Where is the code for your sqlite pull, and specifically the line where the result now alert is created.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy edited.

Answer (score 0):

Move anything you want to happen after the DB transaction has returned or failed in either the success or error handlers, I just moved them out of the arguments and gave them names to keep track of them. and then added your comment to the end of the successCallback handler. Anything you want to happen after a transaction was not successful use the error callback.

```
 function successCallback(tx, results) {
 var len = results.rows.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     custBal = results.rows.item(i).customerBalance;
     alert("result row" + results.rows.item(i).customerBalance);
     alert("CustomerBal" + custBal);
 }


 alert("Total after entitled discount: ");
 alert("Transaction successful, Next Customer Please");
 }

 function errorCallback(tx, error) {

 }

 myDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
     alert("Hello");
     transaction.executeSql("SELECT customerBalance FROM customer where nric = '" + myTextTwo + "'", [], successCallback, errorCallback);
 });
```

Comment: what if we have multiple sql statement?

Comment: If you need to make a second sql transaction after the first has completed, put the myDB.transaction(sql select code) function inside the success callback, creating another callback in there.  The callbacks don't get called until the data is returned